# What is the pupose of the tsconfig.editor.json file in a nx workspace?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

If one create a nx workspace for angular (or adds a new project to an existing workspace), nx generates a `tsconfig.editor.json` in the project folder. This file is listed e.g. on the [NX Angular tutorial](https://nx.dev/angular-tutorial/01-create-application#create-a-new-workspace).
Searching on the internet for the purpose of this file I found the [PR #3810](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/3810) on github when it was added. The description there is:

> **Current Behavior**
> New files and files that aren't referenced by source files do not have a tsconfig for the > type checker in the IDE.
>
> **Expected Behavior**
> New files and files that aren't referenced by source files have a tsconfig.editor.json for the type checker in the IDE.

But beside that I wasn't able to find a good explanation (with an example) for what this file is for. Could anyone enlighten me, possibly with an example? What IDE's do support / make use of this `tsconfig.editor.json` file?

Comment: yup, that's not entirely clear, especially when moving from the older version of nx, but from the context of that PR and what I see in the code it looks like they want to have some additional tsconfig for all files you might have in your project ( eg including jest tests etc )